# HTML CSS transparency popup for image or youtube embended video

Tags: html, css, image, popup, transparency

i'm working over popup box with opacity of it's background, i've got problem with css: the box is transparency and that work but it's getting transparency for image too, i want thee image to be with opacity 1, nothing works. Any tips?

Google and stackoverflow give nothing usefull in search results.

```css
/*
popup img video
*/

.trans_background{
 position: absolute;
 width: 99%;
 min-height: 98%;
 border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
 background: white;
 opacity: 0.8;
 z-index: 3;
}

.trans_left_box{
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 width: 60%;
 height: 94%;
 border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
 background: white;
 z-index: 3;
 opacity: initial;
}

.trans_left_box_img  > img{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 width: 98%;
 height: 92%;
 border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
 background: black;
 opacity: initial;
 z-index: 4;
}

.trans_right_box{
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 61%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 width: 37%;
 height: 94%;
 border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
 background: white;
 z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>socialpages</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="all" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body class="body">
  <div class="trans_background">
   <div class="trans_left_box">
    <div class="trans_left_box_img">
     <img src="bc.jpg" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="trans_right_box">
   </div>    
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGoFy.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify parent divs opacity but make it not affect children HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177497/specify-parent-divs-opacity-but-make-it-not-affect-children-html-elements)